# deepstreamの解析結果動画にミリ秒単位のタイムスタンプを載せる

Tags: ubuntu

deepstreamの解析結果動画にミリ秒単位のタイムスタンプを載せたいのですが、良い方法はありますでしょうか？デフォルトで用意されているshow-clockやclockoverlayでは秒単位までの表示しか行えないようです。

Comment: date コマンドの書式で `%N` を指定するとナノセカンド単位で表示可能です。`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N'`

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらはclock-overlayのtime-formatとして指定するイメージでしょうか？あるいはtext-overlayの引数としてdateの値を渡すイメージでしょうか？

Comment: はい、text-overlayの引数としてdateの値を渡すことになるかと思います。

Comment: 色々と検索してみたのですが、text-overlayを使用して動的にテキストを更新する方法が見つかりませんでした。もしご存じであればご教示いただけないでしょうか。